# LastpaswordchangedDatetime return as longint value instead of datetime ,when i calling graphapi from custom policy( forgot password custom policy)

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, forgot-password

I have called graph api from  forgotpassword custom policy to check the lastpasswordchangedatetime value but it return longint value when i see the  jwt token.**( "lastPasswordChangeDateTime": 1709085348,)**

Below is the custom policy,
I have delcared  lastPasswordChangeDate  claimtype as Datetime, here is my technical profile but

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="GetPasswordPolicies">
<DisplayName>Get Password Policies</DisplayName>
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
<Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{objectId}?$select=lastPasswordChangeDateTime</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpMethod">GET</Item>
    <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>
</Metadata>
<InputClaims>
       <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="lastPasswordChangeDateTime" />
</OutputClaims>
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0clA.png)

I have tried as mentioned above, but lastpasswordchangedDatetime is return as longint value